# Close iFrame On Button Click Within Itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I load an iFrame of another page of my website dynamically. I would like to close the iFrame by clicking on an "X" button within the iFrame. I have created a Jquery function in my main JavaScript file, and I have also added some Javascript to my page frame itself (within my own domain).

In my main JS file:

```
var closeIFrame = function() {
    $('#iframeContact').remove();
    $("#overlay").toggleClass("overflowhidden overflow");
};
```

On my iFrame page (at the bottom of the page's HTML):

```
<script>
$("#menuOverlayBack").click(function(){
    parent.closeIFrame();
}
```

I even have tried putting an "onclick" HTML element on my button to no avail:

```
<i class="menuOverlayBack material-icons" id="menuOverlayBack" onclick="parent.closeIFrame()">arrow_back</i>
```

Comment: was it a typo or are you really missing the closing `);` on your click handler?

Comment: also, is you `closeIFrame` in the global scope or is it wrapped in a document.ready function or somehitng?

Comment: I am facing this issue Blocked a frame with origin "" from accessing a cross-origin frame. when I try to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using jQuery to modify the visibility of the iframe when "x" is clicked..

```
$("#close").click(function() {
  $("#myIframe").css({"display": 'none'});
});
```